# What is the name of this mod in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, mod-identification

At about 12:20:
[image: Screenshot]

The original video

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name of the mod is Not Enough Items. Similar to Too Many Items,but with an additional panel with items.

Answer (score 4):

The mod is known as **NotEnoughItems** (NEI) and can be found over [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1279956-chickenbones-mods) on the Minecraft Forum.

It works very similarly to TooManyItems, except it also contains additions such as an easy way to search and sort items and a Recipe feature that can be used to look up crafting/smelting/other recipes for items and blocks.

Answer (score 3):

If you're saying the thing on the side of your inventory with all the items in the game, that's called Not Enough Items (NEI for short)

Comment: how about the left ?

Comment: That's still nei

Comment: @KentLiau The left allows you to save and load your inventory, as well as some cheats at the top. It is still part of NEI